# pass JTextField from Frame to another class in java

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class mainWindow extends JFrame {
private JTextField jtfCustomerName=new JTextField(8);
private JTextField jtfPassword=new JTextField(20);
Button login;

public mainWindow(){

    JPanel p1=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
    p1.add(new JLabel("Customer name:"));
    p1.add(jtfCustomerName);
     p1.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
    p1.add(jtfPassword);
    login=new Button("login");
    p1.add(login);
    add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            System.out.println("test..");



        }
    });



}


public String getAccNum(){
    return jtfCustomerName.getText();
}
 public String getPassword(){
    return jtfPassword.getText();
}
    }
```

so this is a simple GUI class, user can enter accountNum and password,and then click a button.I want to send accountNum and password to another class.

```
public class CustomerLoginGUIAPP {


   public static void main(String[] args) {


        mainWindow main=new mainWindow();
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.setSize(600,400);
        main.setLocation(300,300);
        System.out.println("Account num is " + ????);
        }}
```

this is the main class, i want to get the account number and password here. I have tried a couple of ways, i all get NULL value. I read some posts and i know i need to use constructor. I don't very understand it form other posts, So i have to ask for help.

```
public class customer {


private String AccNum;
private String password;

public customer(String AccNum,String password){
this.AccNum=AccNum;
this.password=password;

}    

public String getAccNum(){
return AccNum;
}

public String getPassword(){
return password;
}
 public void setAccNum(String AccNum) {
    this.AccNum = AccNum;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
} 
}
```

since i know i should use constructor, so i create this class. But i don't know how to real use it. I know basic constructor(customer c=new customer("s123","abdcd"); then if i want to get accNum, i can use "c.getAccNum()").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good pattern is to have your window create some sort of result object that the person who displays the window can get when the window disappears. I'd change your MainWindow class to be something like this:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    private JTextField jtfCustomerName=new JTextField(8);
    private JTextField jtfPassword=new JTextField(20);
    private Customer result;

    public MainWindow(){

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Customer name:"));
        p1.add(jtfCustomerName);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
        p1.add(jtfPassword);
        Button login = new Button("login");
        p1.add(login);
        add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                result = new Customer(jtfCustomerName.getText(), jtfPassword.getText()); //set the result here
                setVisible(false); //hide this window
            }
        });
    }

    public Customer getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

And then you access it in your CustomerLoginGUIAPP like so:

```
public class CustomerLoginGUIAPP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow main= new MainWindow();
        main.setSize(600,400);
        main.setLocation(300,300);
        main.setVisible(true);
        Customer customer = main.getResult(); //get the saved result
        System.out.println("Account num is " + customer.getAccNum());
    }
}
```

Then keep your Customer class the same.

Comment: Note that I capitalized all of your class names to follow the Java naming conventions. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html You will get a couple errors if you just copy/paste straight into your existing files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast the object to your mainWindow. This way you can enter the public methods.

// do it like this:

```
public class mainWindow {
....
private static customer person; // NEW

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mainWindow main=new mainWindow();
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setSize(600,400);
    main.setLocation(300,300);
    login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
          System.out.println("test..");
          final int accNum = getAccNum();
          final String password = getPassword();
          createCustomer(accNum, password);
        }
    });
}

private static void createCustomer(int accNum, String password) {
    person = new customer(accNum, password);
    System.out.println("It works -> Customer: " + person.getAccNum() + " - " + person.getPassword());
}
```

Comment: this way it creates a customer with the accnum and the password you insert

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but i have tried it before. And i tried again, it doesn't work. It will only print "It works->Customer -" BEFORE i enter the accNum and password.

Comment: Now, after you press the login button, you will create the customer called in this example "person". Hope this solves your mistery :)